# Improve Web Scraping for Elements in a Container Using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using FireFox, and my code is working just fine, except that its very slow. I prevent loading the images, just to speed up a little bit:

```
firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
firefox_profile.set_preference('permissions.default.image', 2)
firefox_profile.set_preference('dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.libflashplayer.so', 'false')
firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.privatebrowsing.autostart", True)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=firefox_profile)
```

but the performance is still slow. I have tried going headless but unfortunately, it did not work, as I receive NoSuchElement errors. So is there anyway to speed up Selenium web scraping? I can't use scrapy, because this is a dynamic web scrape I need to click through the next button several times, until no clickable buttons exist, and need to click pop-up buttons as well.

here is a snippet of the code:

```
a = []
b = []
c = []
d = []
e = []
f = []
while True:
    container = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class,"review-container")]')
    for item in container:
        time.sleep(2)
        A = item.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class,"ui_bubble_rating bubble_")]')
        for i in A:
            a.append(i,text)
        time.sleep(2)
        B = item.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class,"recommend-titleInline noRatings")]')
        for j in B:
            b.append(j.text)
        time.sleep(3)
        C = item.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class,"noQuotes")]')
        for k in C:
            c.append(k.text)
        time.sleep(3)
        D = item.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class,"ratingDate")]')
        for l in D:
            d.append(l.text)
        time.sleep(3)
        E = item.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class,"partial_entry")]')
        for m in E:
            e.append(m.text)

    try:
        time.sleep(2)
        next = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class,"nav next taLnk ui_button primary")]')
        next.click()
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class,"taLnk ulBlueLinks")]').click()
    except (ElementClickInterceptedException,NoSuchElementException) as e:
        break
```

Here is an edited version, but speed does not improve.

```
========================================================================
while True:
    container = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class,"review-container")]')
    for item in container:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'.//*[contains(@class,"ui_bubble_rating bubble_")]')))
        A = item.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class,"ui_bubble_rating bubble_")]')
        for i in A:
            a.append(i.text)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'.//*[contains(@class,"recommend-titleInline noRatings")]')))
        B = item.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class,"recommend-titleInline noRatings")]')
        for i in B:
            b.append(i.text)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'.//*[contains(@class,"noQuotes")]')))
        C = item.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class,"noQuotes")]')
        for i in C:
            c.append(i.text)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'.//*[contains(@class,"ratingDate")]')))
        D = item.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class,"ratingDate")]')
        for i in D:
            d.append(i.text)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'.//*[contains(@class,"partial_entry")]')))
        E = item.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class,"partial_entry")]')
        for i in E:
            e.append(i.text)

    try:
        #time.sleep(2)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'.//*[contains(@class,"nav next taLnk ui_button primary")]')))
        next = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class,"nav next taLnk ui_button primary")]')
        next.click()
        WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'.//*[contains(@class,"taLnk ulBlueLinks")]')))
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class,"taLnk ulBlueLinks")]').click()
    except (ElementClickInterceptedException,NoSuchElementException) as e:
        break
```

Comment: You have 17 seconds sleep in each iteration of the `while`. Do you think it might have something to do with it?

Comment: Consider to use [Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#waits) instead of numerous sleeps to decrease execution time. Also note that if you do web-scraping you should use Selenium only as last resort. You can try to get required data with direct API call using, for instance, [`request` lib](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

Comment: @Guy, I am also suspecting the same thing, I am looking for a more optimized way to scrape texts in a container, that has a next button at the, and an annoying pop-up.

Comment: Couple of things, although not sure it is going to make much difference. First, may be you don't need all these waits in the for loop, if presence of one element guarantees other. Like, clicking gives you a new row and all the elements present in the new row. Also wait until returns you the elements you are looking for. No need for another call to fetch the elements. Also I think in each call you are trying to gather all the elements again, given the xpath. As is your list might be something like 1,1,2,1,2,3 kind of pattern.

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic webpages(pages rendered or augmented using javascript),  I will suggest you use [scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash)

Not that you can't use selenium but for scrapping purposes scrapy-splash is a better fit.

Also, if you have to use selenium for scraping a good idea would be to use headless option. And also you can use chrome. I had some benchmarks for chrome headless being faster than firefox headless sometimes back.

Also, rather than sleep better would be to use webdriverwait with expected condition as it waits as long as necessary rather than thread sleep, which makes you to wait for the mentioned time.

Edit : Adding as edit while trying to answer @QHarr, as the answer is pretty long.

It is a suggestion to evaluate scrapy-splash.

I gravitate towards to scrapy because the whole eco system around scrapping purposes. Like middleware, proxies, deployment, scheduling, scaling. So bascially if you are looking for some serious scrapping scrapy might be better starting position. So that suggestion comes with caveat.

At the coming to speed, I can't give any objective answer, as I have never contrasted and benchmarked scrapy with selenium from time perspective with any project of size.

But I would assume more or less you will be able to get comparable times, on a serial run, if you are doing the same things. As most cases the time you spend is on waiting for responses.

If you scrapping with any considerable no of items, the speed-up you get is by generally parallelising the requests. Also in cases, falling back to basic http request and response where it is not necessary, rather to render the page in any user agent.

Also, anecdotally, some of the in web page action can be performed using the underlying http request/response. So time is a priority then you should be looking to get as many thing as possible done with http request/response.

Comment: Why is scrapy-splash a better fit please? Is it faster?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but going headless have provided me with NoSuchElement error. I tried to solve the problem by replicating the solutions provided by people here in stackoverflow, but to no avail, so I have reverted back to being "not" headless.

Comment: Interesting, If you can provide an url or workable solution I can have a look or post as question so that other community member can look ? I have seen this issue of NoSuchElementException for headless mode for couple of different reason.